# Find cell location using ItemMouseHover List View Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Anyone know if it's possible to find the cell location using ItemMouseHover event for a list view. e doesn't give location.

Private Sub ListView1_ItemMouseHover(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs, postion As MouseEventArgs) Handles lvw.ItemMouseHover

End Sub

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by cell location?  The X,Y?  relative to the form or the control?  You might want the `MouseHover` event for the control rather than item

Comment: Something similar to this:     Private Sub lvw_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lvw.MouseDown
    Dim info = lvw.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    Dim row = info.Item.Index
    Dim col = info.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem)
    Dim value = info.Item.SubItems(col).Text
    MsgBox(String.Format(String.Format("R{0}:C{1} val '{2}'", row, col, value)))
  End Sub

Comment: I'm trying to find what column and row the cell is located in.

Comment: `e.Item.Index` will tell you the "row" .otherwise use the mouse coords to find the Subitem